# VBA Excel - copy certain values to designated tabs when changes in document occur

Tags: excel, vba

Good day,

After much trial and error I hope that someone can maybe help me with the following.

I have a document with a number of sheets. 'Sheet1' is an overview of all sales orders (displaying both open and closed ones) that are entered through a userform. 
The other sheets are customer specific sheets that only list the sales order for that specific client (also displaying both open and closed orders).

Now I would like to have a 'Worksheet Change Event' that automatically updates the client specific sheet when data is entered in "Sheet1". And when you change data in 'Sheet 1' at a later stage again (for example you set the customer order from "open" to "closed" then it should update the matching cell or row for that customer in their respective sheet.

I am not sure if this is possible or if it should be a 'Button_Click' macro?

Here are some pictures of what it should look like:
Sheet1
[image: Sheet1]
Customer ABC
[image: Customer ABC]

Comment: It's possible but it doesn't make sense. The way to go is to have one sheet which has all the data and all the updates, and create different views of that same sheet showing only some data, for example the orders of one particular client. The normal way of creating the sub-views would be to use a filter. You might use VBA to apply the filter. If you must, you can save the filtered result to a separate worksheet but you shouldn't think of updating that sheet. Instead, create a new one whenever you need an update.